# Impossivel navegar uma combo com o scroll do mouse no IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rolamento, internet-explorer-9

Quando selecionado uma combo e é usado o scroll do mouse a tela desce ao invés da lista da combo. Isso somente ocorre no browser do IE9 e IE10.
Poderiam me ajudar com esse problema? Estou usando bootstrap, seria algum compomente específico?

Comment: Você pode postar seu código HTML?